# How set shadow color of header in TeeChart?

Tags: java, android, teechart

Using `TChart` in Android. I'm trying to add a shadow to the chart header, but I can't set its color. It's always white!

```
// chart.getHeader().getFont().getShadow().setColor(Color.fromArgb(0xffff0000));
chart.getHeader().getFont().getShadow().getBrush().setVisible(true);
chart.getHeader().getFont().getShadow().getBrush().setColor(Color.fromArgb(0xffff0000));
chart.getHeader().getFont().getShadow().setSize(2);
chart.getHeader().getFont().getShadow().setSmooth(false);
```

What more do I need to get a shadow of a different color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right. It seems that the Title Font Shadow is always drawn in the same color than the Title and if you try to change the color of the shadow it doesn't apply. I've added it to the defect list to be revised for future releases (TJ71016479).

I recommend you to be aware at the following channels for new release announcements and what's implemented on them:

- [Support forum](http://www.teechart.net/support/index.php)
- [RSS news feed](http://www.steema.com/rss)
- [Twitter](http://twitter.com/SteemaSoftware)
- [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/SteemaSoftware)

Comment: Thanks. Where can I see planned maintenance releases?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. What you can see is the release notes of the releases that have been published here and follow Steema's news, facebook or twitter for new release announces.

Comment: This is just to let you know this has just been fixed for the next maintenance release.